# Angular js scope between directive and controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have to show user login page in pop up and have to validate user name and password with the server by using angular js. I create one app model file, and one controller, service and one directive. My code looks like bellow,

app.js

```
angular.module('mint', ['ngAnimate', 'toastr']);
```

mycontroller.js

```
angular.module('mint').controller(
        'headercontroller',
        [
                '$scope',
                'headerservice',
                'toastr',
                function($scope, headerservice, toastr) {
$scope.showModal = false;

                    $scope.toggleModal = function() { 
                        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
                    };
$scope.userSignin = function(){
                        $scope.userloginbtn = false;
                        if($scope.signin_form.$valid){  //Error on this line signin_form is undefine. using $valid for undefine
                            var record = {};
                            angular.extend(record, $scope.signinForm);
                            console.log(record);
                        }else {
                            $scope.signin_form.submitted = false;
                            $scope.userloginbtn = true;
                        }
                    };
} ]);
```

my directive.js file is

```
angular
        .module('mint')
        .directive(
                'modal',
                function() {
                    return {
                        template : '<div class="modal fade">'
                                + '<div class="modal-dialog">'
                                + '<div class="modal-content">'
                                + '<div class="modal-header">'
                                + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'
                                + '<h4 class="modal-title"><span><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ title }}</span></h4>'
                                + '</div>'
                                + '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>'
                                + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>',
                        restrict : 'E',
                        transclude : true,
                        replace : true,
                        scope : true,
                        link : function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                            scope.title = attrs.title;

                            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value) { 
                                if (value == true)
                                    $(element).modal('show');
                                else
                                    $(element).modal('hide');
                            });

                            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                                scope.$apply(function() {
                                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                                });
                            });

                            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                                scope.$apply(function() {
                                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    };
                });
```

My html file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mintmygold">
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid ban_bg"
        ng-controller="headercontroller">
        <div class="but_bg">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn_sin" ng-click="toggleModal()">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Sign In</span>
                    </button>
        </div>

        <modal title="Login" visible="showModal">
                <form role="form" name="signin_form" class="signup_form" novalidate
                    ng-model="signin_form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p class="infoMsg" ng-model="signinform_info">Please fill in your login credentials:</p>
                    </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input ng-model="signinForm.userEmail" name="userEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required />
                    <div
                                ng-show="signin_form.$submitted || signin_form.userEmail.$touched">
                                <span ng-show="signin_form.userEmail.$error.required">Enter your
                                    email.</span> <span ng-show="signin_form.userEmail.$error.email">This
                                    is not a valid email.</span>
                            </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input ng-model="signinForm.userPassword" name="userPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                    <div
                                ng-show="signin_form.$submitted || signin_form.userPassword.$touched">
                                <span ng-show="signin_form.userPassword.$error.required">Enter your
                                    password.</span>
                            </div>
                  </div>
                  <button ng-disabled="signin_form.$invalid || !userloginbtn" ng-model="signin" ng-click="userSignin()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </modal>
        </div></body></html>
```

Now i can show the popup when click on sign in button. When i submit the form i couldn't get the values of email and password values from the pop up form in controller. what is my mistake of using the scope. Please any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

With a quick overlook, it seems a silly mistake. Change your lines

From

```
angular.module('mint', ['ngAnimate', 'toastr']);
```

To

```
angular.module('mintmygold', ['ngAnimate', 'toastr']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using scope: true which means your directive is creating a child scope and inheriting the properties from its parent. 
Therefore any property you define in the directive scope does not exists on you controller scope.

Changing form name=signin_form
 for form name=$parent.signin_form or scope: false should fix the problem

I didn't  test this though. And it's not a good solution. 
I would probably create a service that launches the pop-up and returns a promise that gets resolved/rejected accordingly.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, modal) {
  $scope.launch = function(){
    modal.show().then(function(user){
      console.log(user)
    }, function(err){
      console.log(err)
    });  
  }


});

app.factory('modal', ["$document", "$compile", "$rootScope", "$templateCache", "$timeout", "$q",
  function ($document, $compile, $rootScope, $templateCache, $timeout, $q) {
    var $body = $document.find('body');

    return {
      show: function(){
        var defer = $q.defer(),
            child = $rootScope.$new();

        child.user = {};

        child.close = function(){
          defer.reject('canceled');
          tpl.remove();
        }

        child.submit = function(){
          defer.resolve(child.user);
          tpl.remove();
        }

        var tpl = angular.element($templateCache.get('modal.html'));
        $compile(tpl)(child);
        $body.append(tpl);

        return defer.promise;
      }
    };

}]);
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    <div class="modal in" style="position: static; display: block">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form ng-submit="submit()" class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
              Email: <input ng-model="user.email"></input><br>
              Password: <input ng-model="user.password"></input>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
<button type="button" ng-click="launch()" class="btn btn-primary">Show modal</button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jtqF5GAc70wdEsCvWP7B?p=preview)

This is just a proof of concept. I think is enough to get you started. I'd strongly recommend to checkout [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and the way the implement their modal

Comment: I checked this with changed form name with $parent.signin_form it's working now. Thanks lot. could you please send me the link using pop up by service